# Safari web inspector cannot be docked

Tags: safari, web-inspector

The web inspector somehow got detached from the main window. Apparently this is a significant problem because I see lots of articles about how to get it docked. Usually they refer to going out of full screen mode, and clicking on the controls.

However, no matter what I do, there are no such controls. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Where in this screen shot are the controls for docking the window? Or how do you get them to display?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if you enter Responsive Design Mode, then the docking icons appear. So immediate problem solved. But I suggest this is a bug when the icons do not appear in "normal" mode.